# Seahorse does not decrpypt under ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, encryption, gnupg, seahorse

I have recently installed a fresh ubuntu 16. I have also imported my PGP key (privat and public) in seahorse. However seahorse did not show the key and did not show the decrypt menu entry for encrypted files.

After looking around I "gpg --import" the privat and public key and was able to "gpg --decrypt" files. However, seahorse still did not show the key and did not offer the decrypt option in the file manager (despite seahorse-nautilus installed).

I then "gpg2 --import" my key, and now seahorse shows the key and offers the decrypt option in the file manager. However, wenn clicking this, it does not ask for the passphrase and instead tries to decrypt the file without passphrase and after a while says: "Could not decrypt file. Probably you are missing the corresponding key" (Or something like this, I am using the German language on my PC).

Is there a possibility to fix this and to use seahorse from the file manager again to decrypt files (as it worked with ubuntu 14)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seahorse relies on GnuPG 2 installed as `gpg2`, not GnuPG 1.4 installed as `gpg`.

Ubuntu 16.04 ships GnuPG 2.1, which moved private keys from the private keyring file into the `pubring.gpg`. Export the private keys in `gpg` and import them in `gpg2` to copy them:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys | gpg2 --import
```

Comment: Great, that worked. Now everything seems like expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, consider selecting the checkmark on the left (see the [FAQ] for details).